# Why is onCreate crashing Android App when I call onClick?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-viewpager, oncreate

I'm trying to load a new view when I push a Button. I have a viewPager and the button is on those views. When I call onClick my app never starts, it crashes before anything happens. I've  been trying to squash this bug for over a week and I think it's something very amateur. Please help a student programmer!

```
public class Main extends Activity {

    Button listButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);

        SplashPager adapter = new SplashPager();
        ViewPager myPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.splashPager);
        myPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        myPager.setCurrentItem(0);

        listButtonListener();
    }

    public void listButtonListener() {

        listButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.splashB);
        listButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                setContentView(R.layout.list_layout);

            }

        });

    }

}
```

Log:

```
01-16 20:09:49.149: W/dalvikvm(29035): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception         (group=0x40207560)
01-16 20:09:49.149: E/AndroidRuntime(29035): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-16 20:09:49.149: E/AndroidRuntime(29035): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.survtest2/com.example.survtest2.Main}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-16 20:09:49.149: E/AndroidRuntime(29035):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1658)
01-16 20:09:49.149: E/AndroidRuntime(29035):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1674)
01-16 20:09:49.149: E/AndroidRuntime(29035):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
01-16 20:09:49.149: E/AndroidRuntime(29035):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:942)
01-16 20:09:49.149: E/AndroidRuntime(29035):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-16 20:09:49.149: E/AndroidRuntime(29035):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
01-16 20:09:49.149: E/AndroidRuntime(29035):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3733)
01-16 20:09:49.149: E/AndroidRuntime(29035):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-16 20:09:49.149: E/AndroidRuntime(29035):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-16 20:09:49.149: E/AndroidRuntime(29035):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:892)
01-16 20:09:49.149: E/AndroidRuntime(29035):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:650)
01-16 20:09:49.149: E/AndroidRuntime(29035):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-16 20:09:49.149: E/AndroidRuntime(29035): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-16 20:09:49.149: E/AndroidRuntime(29035):    at com.example.survtest2.Main.listButtonListener(Main.java:36)
01-16 20:09:49.149: E/AndroidRuntime(29035):    at com.example.survtest2.Main.onCreate(Main.java:30)
01-16 20:09:49.149: E/AndroidRuntime(29035):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
01-16 20:09:49.149: E/AndroidRuntime(29035):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1622)
01-16 20:09:49.149: E/AndroidRuntime(29035):    ... 11 more
01-16 20:09:49.149: E/AndroidRuntime(29035): [Blue Error Handler] Make Debugging Report file for main
01-16 20:09:49.149: E/AndroidRuntime(29035): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.survtest2/com.example.survtest2.Main}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-16 20:09:49.149: E/AndroidRuntime(29035):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1658)
01-16 20:09:49.149: E/AndroidRuntime(29035):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1674)
01-16 20:09:49.149: E/AndroidRuntime(29035):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
01-16 20:09:49.149: E/AndroidRuntime(29035):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:942)
01-16 20:09:49.149: E/AndroidRuntime(29035):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-16 20:09:49.149: E/AndroidRuntime(29035):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
01-16 20:09:49.149: E/AndroidRuntime(29035):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3733)
01-16 20:09:49.149: E/AndroidRuntime(29035):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-16 20:09:49.149: E/AndroidRuntime(29035):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-16 20:09:49.149: E/AndroidRuntime(29035):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:892)
01-16 20:09:49.149: E/AndroidRuntime(29035):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:650)
01-16 20:09:49.149: E/AndroidRuntime(29035):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-16 20:09:49.149: E/AndroidRuntime(29035): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-16 20:09:49.149: E/AndroidRuntime(29035):    at com.example.survtest2.Main.listButtonListener(Main.java:36)
01-16 20:09:49.149: E/AndroidRuntime(29035):    at com.example.survtest2.Main.onCreate(Main.java:30)
01-16 20:09:49.149: E/AndroidRuntime(29035):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
01-16 20:09:49.149: E/AndroidRuntime(29035):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1622)
01-16 20:09:49.149: E/AndroidRuntime(29035):    ... 11 more
```

splash.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/splashPager"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</LinearLayout>
```

splash2.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:src="@drawable/intro__1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/splashB"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_marginLeft="75dp"
    android:text="aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" />

</FrameLayout>
```

ViewPager:

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 4;
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) collection.getContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    int resId = 0;
    switch (position) {

    case 0:
        resId = R.layout.splash2;
        break;
    case 1:
        resId = R.layout.splash3;
        break;
    case 2:
        resId = R.layout.splash4;
        break;
    case 3:
        resId = R.layout.splash5;
        break;

    }

    View view = inflater.inflate(resId, null);
    ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view, 0);
    return view;

}

@Override
public void destroyItem(View arg0, int arg1, Object arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ((ViewPager) arg0).removeView((View) arg2);
}

@Override
public Parcelable saveState() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return arg0 == ((View) arg1);
}

}
```

Comment: what code is at line 36, where you got the null pointer ref?

Comment: listButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

Comment: Also, what's in R.layout.splash?  I think it should be exclusively the ViewPager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your failure at listButton.setOnClickListener, I'm guessing that R.id.splashB is not being found in your layout.

```
public class Main extends Activity {

Button listButton;
View splash2;  // Added

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ...
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);
    SplashPager adapter = new SplashPager();
    ViewPager myPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.splashPager);
    ....
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater(); // Added
    splash2 = inflater.inflate (R.layout.splash2, null); // Added
    myPager.add (splash2); // Added

    listButtonListener();
}

public void listButtonListener() {

    listButton = (Button) splash2.findViewById(R.id.splashB); // Changed
    listButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            setContentView(R.layout.list_layout);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: It's there. I've tried that many times. Renamed it many times.

Comment: According to your XML post, you have the button in Splash2, but in the code above, you are loading Spash.  That is your problem.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to access a button on my viewPager and be able to use it? Please.

Comment: First, you now realize that you need to call findViewById for splash2.xml.  That means you'll have to load splash2.xml.  I'm not entirely sure what behaviour you want, but I think in onCreate you need to load splash2 and put it in the ViewPager - that is, myPager.  Then, in listButtonListener, you need to get that page out of myPager and call findViewById on it.  Alternatively, you can save splash2 in a member variable and use that in listButtonListener.  Make sense?

Comment: splash2 is simply a view for the viewPager. viewPager allows me to swipe between 4 views. I have to load "splash.xml" to load the viewPager. I don't understand what a member variable is. I think this is a basic problem. It's trying to load something thats not there. I guess I need to go back to the basics.

Comment: Correct: splash2 is a view for the viewPager.  But, the spashB button is in splash2.  Therefore you must do something like splash2.findViewById (R.id.splashPager).  To answer your second question, define a variable: "View splash2" where you have "Button listButton" (those are member variables).  Then, in onCreate, load splash2 and save it in the variable splash2.  Give me a momment and I'll post some of this code above.

Comment: Any luck?  Let me know if you need any more help.

Comment: I found the problem, its this code here

public void destroyItem(View arg0, int arg1, Object arg2) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  ((ViewPager) arg0).removeView((View) arg2);

i;m still a new programmer and I don't know how to use this method. This method is cause the layouts to be destroyed and that's why splashB is null. Please help!

Comment: Good!  You must have had some other code (not shown) that created splash2.  But, certainly, if it got deleted, splashB won't be found.  Mind if I get an upvote for sticking with you?

Comment: I need 15 rep to upvote, but any other way I can help please let me know. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You get a `NullPointerException`, probably because `listButton` is `null`. Make sure `splashB` actually exists in the `splash` layout.

If that's not the answer, try setting a break point on `listButtonListener()` to figure out why it throws `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Yes, I've checked it many many times for simple errors like a misspelling. If I remove listButtonListener it doesn't crash. How can I make a button with an onClick?

Comment: That button is in `splash2` but you're using `splash` with `setContentView(R.layout.splash);`

Answer (score -1):

You should try removing

```
myPager.setCurrentItem(0);
```

You don't need this here, since by default ViewPager default page is 0.
This way you are trying to display page which might not be created by Android system.

EDIT:

```
public class Main extends Activity {

Button listButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);

    SplashPager adapter = new SplashPager(this); // PASSING MAIN ACTIVITY FOR SETTING CONTENTVIEW
    ViewPager myPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.splashPager);
    myPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}...}
```

// your adapter code

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) collection.getContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    int resId = 0;
    switch (position) {

    case 0:
        resId = R.layout.splash2;
        break;
    case 1:
        resId = R.layout.splash3;
        break;
    case 2:
        resId = R.layout.splash4;
        break;
    case 3:
        resId = R.layout.splash5;
        break;

    }

    View view = inflater.inflate(resId, null);
    if(resId == R.layout.splash2) {
       Button b = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.splashB);
       b.setOnClickListner(new OnClickListener() {
       @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // mainActivity is Activity variable passed in Adapter constructor
            mainActivity.setContentView(R.layout.list_layout);

        }
       });
    }
    ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view, 0);
    return view;

}
```

Comment: This just isn't an answer. There's no reason this would cause a crash and saying "try this..." with no real explanation of how this could be the cause of the Exception is not an answer.

Comment: Explanation is really simple, he can't get Button ListButton view since it hasn't been created by Android application yet. Calling setCurrentItem would try to load data which doesn't exists.

Comment: Please tell me how to fix this. I knew it was something simple.

Comment: If you are using Eclipse, add breakpoint on that line.
I think it is problem with findViewById(). You should get View from ViewGroup of ViewPager and then call findViewById() on it to get that button.

Comment: Even better solution is to add your onClick listner to adapter you created since you are getting focused View in it.

Comment: Watch this video for android eclipse debuging http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JqHYbm9e05A

Comment: Can you please put your adapter class(SplashPager) so I can tell you where should you put your onClickListener?

Comment: How would I add my listener to the adapter? Thank you for the video.

Comment: Can I use a try catch or a if else or something, I can't believe this is so complicated.

Comment: Try adding this code in your ViewPager:
after : `View view = inflater.inflate(resId, null);`, put 
`Button b = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.splashB);
b.setOnClickListenr(youronclicklistner)` and remove on click listener in your main activity.

Comment: Also, I am not sure do you have this button in splash3,4 etc, so you should add also `if(position==0)` or `if(resId==R.layout.splash2)` before code I gave you so you can catch only splash2 view.

Comment: Be aware, setContentView is not visable by your adapter! You can pass your MainActivity to your adapter and then call setContentView.

Comment: How do I implement Activity in SplashPager so I can use setContentView?

Comment: I removed those buttons because I want to load a new view and still use viewPager and I've been working on this for a week now and I still can't figure this out. I just want anything to work now, thank you very much for this.

Comment: How do I pass in my MainActivity?

Comment: Give me your Adapter constructor

Comment: Wow it's still saying that Button b is null.

Comment: It's the ViewPager, it's not letting me access the button id for some reason.

Comment: Try placing new code after `((ViewPager) collection).addView(view, 0);` or try finding view on collection View. Need to go now, good luck!